# ClosedXML высота строки

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

Небходимо заполнять файл Excel определенными данными. Ширина столбцов должна быть фиксированной, а высота строки увеличиваться в зависимости от записанного в ячейку текста. Пытаюсь использовать метод `AdjustToContents()` (естественно после заполнения), для всех строк, либо только для определенной, но ничего не меняется. Пробовал делать перед использованием метода `Style.Alignment.WrapText = true`, тоже никакого результата. Ранее это делалось через Interop библиотеку, но теперь это стало невозможно. Есть мысли?

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648469/using-closedxml-how-to-adjust-row-height-to-content)?

Comment: @Vlad да, я видел эту тему, но мне из нее ничего не помогло. Установка свойства WrapText в true не помогает ни с использованием AdjustToContents(), ни без него. Попробовал всеми указанными в той теме способами.

Comment: а можно увидеть скриншот как сейчас выглядит результат?

Comment: @FoggyFinder, [скриншот](http://i94.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0706/ee/112e9c48aecccbf4fa80ee97e8b29aee.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Сталкивался с подобным кейсом. Авто-увеличение высоты строки при росте содержимого ячейки перестает работать, если высоте строки задать какое-то значение — даже если указать `Row.SetHeight(Row.Height)` (деталей реализации не помню, но что-то вроде этого). Суть оказалась в том, что покуда высота строки не задана явным образом, при сохранении оно записывается как `null` — и в этом случае автоподбор высоты строки срабатывает как надо.

Я заявлял это как баг (https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/352), и вроде бы в версии 0.89 это должно быть исправлено (но сам я еще не проверял, к сожалению).

Comment: Хм. Там точно не задавалась высота нигде из кода, но вероятно она считается заданной из-за того, что там есть шаблонный лист, который копируется для заполнения данных (определенное кол-во строк на страницу должно быть). Как доберусь снова до той задачи, попробую явно задать null высоту.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio C# CloseXML

Столбец  - Ширина
xlWorkSheet1.Column(1).Width = 10.71;

строка - Высота
xlWorkSheet1.Row(1).Height = 32.25;

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]